# Do Azure Elastic Database Pools allow Cross Database transactions?

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-design, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

We have Stage database, which contains stored procedures, and transfers data into an OLTP Database.

Do Elastic SQL Databases reside on same server, and give ability to conduct cross-db stored procedure transactions?

Would Elastic databasepool allow this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve elastic transactions spanning across databases using .NET client applications. This is currently under preview.

Elastic transactions at server side are planned in future.

[for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview)