# Azure Elastic Database Pools, What is the Maximum Storage Capacity for a Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-design, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

What is the maximum allowed storage capacity for a database for Azure SQL Elastic pool?

We expect our database to be say 25-50 TB. Is this permitted?

I saw something on Github saying its allowed, however did not see in  a Microsoft source.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale.md#p11-and-p15-constraints-when-max-size-greater-than-1-tb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the limit is 1 TB per database on an elastic pool. More than 1 TB of storage in the Premium tier is currently available in all regions except: China East, China North, Germany Central, Germany Northeast, West Central US, US DoD regions, and US Government Central. In these regions, the storage max in the Premium tier is limited to 1 TB. For more information, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-elastic-pools) documentation.

If you expect your database to grow to 25-50 TB then your best option is [Hyperscale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale) that supports up to 100 TB. Elastic pools fall very short of your needs.

Comment: hmm, interesting do they allow two hyper scale 20TB databases which allow cross database transactions? I have question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405492/do-azure-elastic-database-pools-allow-cross-database-transactions?noredirect=1&lq=1 feel free to answer this also, and I can send points, I accepted this question

Comment: I wen to bed after I answer your question. Sorry for not answer your second question.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible. Kindly refer below link,
In the General Purpose tier, you are charged for Premium blob storage that you provision for your database or elastic pool. Storage can be configured between 5 GB and 4 TB with 1 GB increments.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/elastic/

Either vCore or DTU model. Max 4TB.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other hints for finding out the recently assigned max size you can log in to your Azure EP Database and run the below code:

Declare @DB varchar(150)= DB_Name()
SELECT @DB SQL_Database
,cast (Cast(DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@DB, 'MaxSizeInBytes') as decimal)/ 1073741824 as int) AS DatabaseDataMaxSizeIn_GigaBytes;